# xcode6 - How to open storyboard in visual mode

Tags: xcode

New user to xcode here. I want to use the storyboard in visual mode, when I double click on the main.storyboard file from the file explorer I only see the text version of it (looks like XML). I am unable to get back to the visual editor mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to `View` > `Standard Editor` > `Show Standard Editor` from Xcode toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Main Storyboard file and Open as  Interface Builder.[image]